# Error in coredata?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios6

I am developing an app that saving an url using coredata.I am defining NSManagedObjectContext,NsManagedObjectModel,NSPersistentStoreCoordinator in CoreDataRepository  object class instead of AppDelegate.I am saving this url using reference of CoreDataRepository.I am getting below error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CoreDataRepository", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in HomeViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in DashBoardUrlViewController.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any idea about this error.Thanks.

Comment: I also tried to do like you did. But I too cant succeed. After that i didnt change these methods NSManagedObjectContext,NsManagedObjectModel,NSPersistentStoreCoordinator from my appdelegate. I started to write a helper class for core data from accessing managed object context from appdelegate only. I think this problem occurs only because when you use core data in other view controllers it start to search the methods in app delegate only. AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication SharedApplication]delegate]; this line will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linker can't find your `CoreDataRepository` class.  Look in your target's Build Phases and add that source or library to either the compile or link phase, depending on where it's defined.

Comment: hi i solved above problem but that url is not showing in an label.It prints "<NSManagedObject: 0x86d1250> (entity: UrlData; id: 0x86d09b0 <x-coredata://A00EB59A-C480-4237-A749-8A40BF908655/UrlData/p1> ; data: <fault>)"

Comment: this is my code                                                         NSArray *recordsData=[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    
    urlMutableArray = (NSMutableArray *)recordsData;
    
    for (int i=0; i<[urlMutableArray count]; i++)
    {
        urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [urlMutableArray objectAtIndex:0]];
        NSLog(@"urlString is %@",urlString);
    }

Comment: It's printing what you told it to print.  That's a description of a Core Data entity, which it the kind of thing that **should** be in your array after a fetch request.  If you want something the entity contains, you'll have to get one of its properties.